# ¿Como guardar datos de geolocalización (lat y long) en variables php?

Tags: php, javascript

verán necesito pasar dos variables de javascript a php, las cuales son de latitud y longitud generadas por la pi de google maps.

```
<!-- Se determina y escribe la localizacion -->
<div id='ubicacion'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
               if (navigator.geolocation) {
                              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(mostrarUbicacion);
               } else {alert("¡Error! Este navegador no soporta la Geolocalización.");}
function mostrarUbicacion(position) {
    var times = position.timestamp;
               var latitud = position.coords.latitude;
               var longitud = position.coords.longitude;
    var altitud = position.coords.altitude;
               var exactitud = position.coords.accuracy;
               var div = document.getElementById("ubicacion");
               div.innerHTML = "Timestamp: " + times + "<br>Latitud: " + latitud + "<br>Longitud: " + longitud + "<br>Altura en metros: " + altitud + "<br>Exactitud: " + exactitud;}
function refrescarUbicacion() {
               navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(mostrarUbicacion);}
</script>

<!-- Se escribe un mapa con la localizacion anterior-->
<div id="demo"></div>
<div id="mapholder"></div>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<button onclick="cargarmap()">Cargar mapa</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function cargarmap(){
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
function showPosition(position)
  {
  lat=position.coords.latitude;
  lon=position.coords.longitude;
  latlon=new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
  mapholder=document.getElementById('mapholder')
  mapholder.style.height='250px';
  mapholder.style.width='500px';
  var myOptions={
  center:latlon,zoom:10,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  mapTypeControl:false,
  navigationControlOptions:{style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL}
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapholder"),myOptions);
  var marker=new google.maps.Marker({position:latlon,map:map,title:"You are here!"});
  }
function showError(error)
  {
  switch(error.code)
    {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      x.innerHTML="Denegada la peticion de Geolocalización en el navegador."
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      x.innerHTML="La información de la localización no esta disponible."
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      x.innerHTML="El tiempo de petición ha expirado."
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      x.innerHTML="Ha ocurrido un error desconocido."
      break;
    }
  }}
</script>
```

Comment: pues para enviar datos desde javascript a php...usa ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal y como te comentan, lo ideal es hacer una llamada por AJAX a un servicio en php que es el encargado de grabar los datos.

Te creas una función en javascript para enviar los datos

```
function mandadatos(latitud,longitud) {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         alert(this.responseText); //Esto muestra la respuesta del servicio de grabado
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "grabalatlong.php?lat=" + latitud + "&long=" + longitud, true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
```

Ahora solo tienes que hacer un servicio en php llamado grabalatlong.php que recibirá por GET los datos lat y long para que los almacenes. Para probar, podrías crear un servicio que simplemente devuelva un texto con las 2 variables y así ver si el alert los muestra.

Comment: mmm mas o menos como seria el archivo grabalatlong.php, disculpa mi ignorancia soy  algo nuevo en esto.

Comment: En el fichero grabalatlong podrás usar las variables siguientes:
$lat = $_GET['lat'];
$long = $_GET['long'];